# High availability distributed Proxy server

Tags: proxy

I am trying to setup a distributed high availability proxy. Each proxy server should be located at different regions. DHCP Server can be used to inform the client machines to use proxy server which is available. Can you suggest a suitable method or some helpful links ? When I checked, solutions are available with  heartbeat and haproxy but I am not sure how it will work if the servers are located in different regions. Thank you

Comment: Hi Gopu, welcome to the site! I don't actually understand what you are asking: Do you want to know how to insert the proxy information into the DHCP payload? Why is this question relevant only to Ubuntu and not to other Linux-based servers?

Comment: @BogdanBiv Actually I was checking if anyone knows how to setup a high availability proxy servers in Linux. Suppose if one goes down, second one come into place and these servers are located in different regions. I have posted the question here first since ubuntu is always my primary choice :)

Answer (score 0):

You ask two distinct things:

1. To configure browsers to use a certain Proxy via DHCP, you need to set up a PAC server like this http://agix.com.au/blog/?p=912. PAC server is a simple HTTP server serving static files. Then add these two lines to your ISC-DHCPD configuration

   `option local-pac-server code 252 = text; 
    option local-pac-server "http://www.example.com/wpad.pac";`
2. To set up a high availability network you need to use a DNS round
   robin scheme: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS

Should you need further help, I'd suggest cutting your post in two (client and server as noted above). Also you should consider moving them to the [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) StackExchange since that is a community dedicated to administrating many servers. People there will have more experience with providing High Availabilty to clients.